# Validate a string containing numbers and colon

Tags: php, regex, forms, validation

I have a `<form>` with an `<input>` that only should contain numbers and colon, like this:

```
$string = '1:9:3:2:0';
```

When I validate user submitted fields, I want to make sure this input is valid. For example, if it was only numbers, I would do an `is_numberic()` check.

How can I validate this string?

Clarification:

```
$string = '1:9:3:2:0'; // pass
$string = '2123:8:1'; // pass
$string = 'a:9:3:2:0'; // fail
$string = '1:9:3:2:'; // fail
$string = '1:9:3:2:0';
```

Is a `regex` statement the way to go?

Comment: `^\d+(?::\d+)+$` ............

Comment: @AvinashRaj Would you do a preg_match() on this? Please post an answer outlining your approach and why it is the appropriate one. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the below regex for field validation.

```
var $m = preg_match('~^\d+(?::\d+)+$~', $str);
```

- `^` - start of the line.
- `\d+` - matches one or more digit chars.
- `:\d+` - A colon and one or more digits.
- `(?::\d+)+` repeats ^^ one or more times.
- `$` End of the line.

Edit:

```
var $m = preg_match('~^\d+(?::\d+)*$~', $str);
```

Comment: Excellent, just one final question. It doesn't seem to work validate $str = '5'; -- any way you can allow this scenario?

Comment: I saw this `$string = '19320'; // fail`, if you want to validate string having only numbers then `^[\d:]+$` would be 5in.

Comment: Yes, this was an error on my part. I have updated the question and removed that line. I want $string = '19320'; to pass.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!